# Elasticsearch some indices unassigned after a brain-split happened

Tags: elasticsearch

Using ES 1.3.1 version
Found a brain-split then restart the entire cluster. Now only the latest index got correctly allocated, leave all other indices unassigned...
I've checked on several nodes, there are index data saved on disk, and I've tried to restart those nodes, still won't get a shard allocate...
Please see this screen shot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6jT7.png

I've tried the "Cluster reroute":　http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-reroute.html. However, got  a exception like "cannot allocate Primary Shard"...

Please help and any comment is welcome. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Don't allocate primary shards with the _cluster/reroute API, this will create an empty shard with no data.

Try setting your replica count to 0.

If that doesn't work, set index.gateway logging to be TRACE and restart a node that contains saved index data for one of the unassigned shards.  What do you see in the logs for that node or in the logs for the master node?